# How to highlight object AND property in Custom eslint rule?

Tags: javascript, plugins, rule, eslint

I've written a custom plugin/rule for linting our js project to find specific object/function combinations.  It works great but one minor annoyance is that I want to highlight **both** the object AND function name when the rule is tripped.

For example, if the following trips the rule:

```
foo.bar("hello world");
```

Then in my editor I'd like **all** of `foo.bar` to be highlighted (the function arguments aren't necessary).

To highlight *just* the object name (e.g., 'foo') I write this in my rule:

```
context.report({
    node: node,
    message: "my rule message"
});
```

and if I wanted to highlight *just* the object property (e.g., 'bar') I write this in my rule:

```
context.report({
    node: node.property,
    message: "my rule message"
});
```

So what should I pass to my `context.report.node` to highlight **both** the object name and property?

Comment: As an aside, is there any documentation for the context object (and other objects used with custom eslint rules?  Seems pretty hard to come by other than generalities and simple examples.